# SQL error using drop commands and create commands

Tags: sql

I have to create a table for a database project but I keep getting two errors.  For the drop code I am returning an error stating sql command not properly ended. For the create table command I keep returning missing or invalid option.

```
drop table Histology Tissue cascade constraints;

create table Histology Tissue
(
HistologyID     VARCHAR (15) PRIMARY KEY, 
Tissue Type     Char (25) NOT NULL,
Date Received   Date,
DonorID         VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
Species         Char (20) NOT NULL, 
Disease type    Char (20) NOT NULL, 
AnimalID        Numeric (15),
constraint PKhistology_tissue primary key (HistologyID),
constraint FKDonorID foreign key (DonorID) references External Sample,
constraint FKAnimalID foreign key (AnimalID references Internal Sample
);

describe Histology Tissue;
```

Comment: Identifiers with spaces have to be quoted, `"Histology Tissue"`, or simply avoided.

Comment: SQL seems broad, would you add the missing database tag, presumably Oracle?

Comment: create table Histology_Tissue
(
HistologyID     VARCHAR (15) PRIMARY KEY, 
Tissue_Type     Char (25) NOT NULL,
Date_Received   Date,
DonorID         VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
Species         Char (20) NOT NULL, 
Disease_type    Char (20) NOT NULL, 
AnimalID        Numeric (15),
constraint PKhistology_tissue primary key (HistologyID),
constraint FKDonorID foreign key (DonorID) references External Sample,
constraint FKAnimalID foreign key (AnimalID) references Internal Sample
);
describe Histology Tissue;

Comment: I am now receiving an error saying missing right parenthesis and I do not see where

Answer (score 0):

For foreign key specify table name and column name of reference table and its primary key.

```
DROP TABLE [histology tissue]  

CREATE TABLE [histology tissue]
 ( histologyid varchar (15) PRIMARY KEY, 
   [tissue type] char (25) NOT NULL, 
   [date received] date, 
   donorid varchar (15) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tablename(donorid), 
   species char (20) NOT NULL, 
   [disease type] char (20) NOT NULL, 
   animalid numeric (15)FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tablename(donorid), 
    )
```